# Notation of Derivative and Differential

Tags: integration, analysis, derivatives, notation, differential

Let $\gamma:[a;b] \to U, \gamma(t)=\big(x(t),y(t)\big)$ be a path. The integral of $\omega$ along $\gamma$ is defined as
$$ \int_\gamma \omega := \int_a^b \omega_x\big(x(t),y(t)\big)\dot{x}(t)+\omega_y\big(x(t),y(t)\big)\dot{y}(t)~ dt$$
where $\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{dt}$, $\dot{y}=\frac{dy}{dt}$.

**My Question:**
What does $\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{dt}$ exactly mean? And could I replace it with $\dot{x}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$?

Comment: Usually partial derivatives symbols are reserved for functions depending on more than one variable. If $x(t)$ only depends on $t$, then $\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{dt}$ looks correct.

Comment: The $\dot{x}$ is just Newton notation for a derivative, you can think of it just like an $x'.$ In physics the $\dot{x}$ notation is often used specifically to refer to a derivative with respect to time. As far as the other question, I agree with the other comment: since $x$ depends only on $t,$ the total derivative is correct.